# Exercise I-21 in Eisenbud-Harris book Geometry of Schemes: the general case

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In this exercise it is asked to compute the ring of fractions of a noetherian ring $R$ defined as 
$$\varinjlim_{U\in \mathfrak{U}}\mathcal{O}_X(U)$$
where $X=\text{Spec}\ R$ and $\mathfrak{U}$ is the set of dense open subsets of $X$.

I believe the setting is too general to be able to describe this ring as usual. $R$ should be supposed to be also reduced to get it. Does anybody have a proof in the general setting of $R$ only supposed to be noetherian?

**Edit**: the exercise actually asks not for the usual total ring of fractions, but for the ring of rational fractions, as it is mentioned in the answer (but I did not know the definition of such a ring)

Comment: Why do you believe that the setting is too general? Did you try an example and get stuck?

Comment: @KReiser Well, the problem is that I do not find the usual ring of fractions (localization of R
 at all the regular elements) but a bigger one (localization at all the elements not belonging to a minimal prime of R
)

Comment: Ah, I had misinterpreted what you wrote. I thought you were stuck, versus having a disagreement with the text. You're correct, of course, that this is not necessarily the ring of fractions in the case that $X$ is not irreducible.

Comment: @KReiser you mean $X$ reduced, not irreducible right?

Comment: Yeah, I meant integral (reduced + irreducible). Too many mistakes for one day already...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Lemma.** You can replace $\mathfrak{U}$ by the set $\mathfrak{U}'$ of elementary affine open subsets $D(f)$ such that $f$ does not belong to any minimal prime of $R$ (which is equivalent to say that $D(f)$ is dense in $X$).

*Proof.* Take $U\in\mathfrak{U}$. Then you can write $F = X\backslash U = V(I)$ for some ideal $I$ of $R$. As $U$ is dense, $F$ does not contain any irreducible component of $X$ (if $U$ doesn't cut an irreducible component then it is contained in the union of the finitely number of others irreducible components, then the closure of $U$ is also be contained in the latter union and $U$ is not dense) and this translates algebraically into the fact that the ideal $I$ is not contained in any minimal prime ideal of $R$. Now if $\mathfrak{p}_x\in U$ you can find (by prime avoidance) an $f\in I$ such that $\mathfrak{p}_x \in D(f)$ and such that $f$ doesn't belong to any minimal prime of $R$, which translates topologically into the fact that $D(f)\subset U$ is dense in $X$. So any element of $\mathfrak{U}$ is covered by sets of $\mathfrak{U}'$, which concludes the lemma.

From this you see that the direct limit you want to calculate is the localization of $R$ at the multiplicative set of elements not contained in any minimal prime. If $R$ is a domain as first supposed in the exercice, then you land in the total ring of fractions of $R$.

What about the case where $R$ is noetherian (but not a domain) ? You land on the ring of rational functions of $X$. But it's not that easy as the formulation of the exercise can let think. (See EGA I, proposition 7.1.5.)

Comment: Your answer achieves to convince me that I do not land in the usual ring of fractions but in $Q^{-1}R$ where $Q$ is the complement of the (finite) union of all the minimal primes (which is usually strictly bigger than the set of regular elements). Thanks for the reference, especially EGA I, proposition 7.1.9 which adresses exactly this issue. I was confused by the name ring of rational functions which I did not learn at this stage in the book!